# Angular 2 "template" vs "templateUrl" issue

Tags: angular, routes

I am building up an app using RouterModule. The problem is that when I use "template" in my Component decoration everything works great, but when I use "templateUrl" instead, the app starts glitching

Console throws: Uncaught (in promise): **Error: Error in app/about.component.html:1:30 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Just don't know what files could be helpful, because it seems like the issue is not there.

*Not working properly*

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

     @Component({
        selector: 'about-block',
        templateUrl: 'app/about.component.html'
     })

   export class AboutComponent {}
```

*Working properly*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
       selector: 'about-block',
       template: '<h1>This is About section</h1>'
    })

   export class AboutComponent {}
```

P.S.

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents}  from './app.routing';

 @NgModule({
       imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule ],
       declarations: [ AppComponent, routingComponents ],
       bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
     })
 export class AppModule { }
```

*about.component.html*

```
   <about-block>

   </about-block>
```

Comment: problem is not here probably in app.module.ts file.

Comment: I'm not sure but somewhere you have `comma` or `dot` error.

Comment: @micronyks Added the app.module.ts file, please take a look

Comment: Here you don't have any error. somewhere in app you have a minor error which causes this issue. You have to figure it out as its hard to say. I just gave you hint. That's it.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov It could be problem with `about.component.html` can you please share your about.component.html?

Comment: @Sanket Updated with the about.component.html file above

Comment: @Sanket was right, that's exactly your problem. Just look at what you're doing, you're trying to create instance of your `AboutComponent` in itself which would result in infinite instances of that same component. Just remove `<about-block></about-block>` from `about.component.html` and add anything else, it'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<about-block></about-block>` from about.component.html

Because of your `about-block` tag in html template, it is going recursive. Hence, you are receiving Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: Can you please explain a little, if I remove the 'about-block' tag from .html, then what does the selector 'about-block'? I mean where is the DOM element with the tag 'about-block' which is supposed to be a container for my template on the page?

Comment: You can add html in your html template like this- `<h1>This is About section</h1>`

Comment: Yeah I understand it, I just have no idea what does the selector in Components decoration, because there's no tag as 'about-block', so it turns to be an abstract name without any reference to real DOM.

Comment: selector is to add this component inside another component.

Because you adding <about-block></about-block> in same component, it was doing like this-
`<about-block><about-block><about-block>....</about-block></about-block></about-block>`
Once memory runs out it will throw error.